# Wrong SQL Aggregate result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get average of a tuple. But my query won't get the result. I cannot find the mistake after hours of research. Please help

MY Query:

```
SELECT  dbo.Objectives.Id,
    dbo.Objectives.Clause, 
    dbo.Objectives.FrequencyId, 
    ObjectiveFrequency.Title AS ObjectiveFrequencyTitle,                
    dbo.Objectives.ObjectiveCategoryId, 
    dbo.ObjectiveCategories.Category AS ObjectiveCategory, 
    dbo.Objectives.Target, 
    dbo.Objectives.TargetUnitId, 
    TargetUOM.Unit AS TargetUnit, 
    TargetUOM.Symbole AS TargetSymbol, 
    TargetUOM.Position AS TargetPosition,               
    AVG(dbo.Achievements.ActualResult) AS AverageResult,
    dbo.Achievements.ActualResultUOMId, 
    ActualResultUOM.Unit AS ActualResultUOMUnit, 
    ActualResultUOM.Symbole AS ActualResultUOMSymbole, 
    ActualResultUOM.Position AS ActualResultUOMPosition 
FROM dbo.Objectives
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Achievements ON dbo.Objectives.Id =   dbo.Achievements.ObjectiveId
    INNER JOIN dbo.UnitOfMeasures AS TargetUOM ON TargetUOM.Id = dbo.Objectives.TargetUnitId                         
    INNER JOIN dbo.Frequencies AS ObjectiveFrequency ON dbo.Objectives.FrequencyId = ObjectiveFrequency.Id 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Employees AS AssignEmployee ON dbo.Objectives.AssignToEmployeeId = AssignEmployee.EmployeeId 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Departments AS AssignDepartment ON dbo.Objectives.AssignedDepartmentDepartmentId = AssignDepartment.DepartmentId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ObjectiveCategories ON dbo.Objectives.ObjectiveCategoryId = dbo.ObjectiveCategories.Id  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UnitOfMeasures ValueUOM ON    dbo.Achievements.ValueUOMId = ValueUOM.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UnitOfMeasures VaryValuUOM ON  dbo.Achievements.VaryValueUOMId = VaryValuUOM.Id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UnitOfMeasures ActualResultUOM ON dbo.Achievements.ActualResultUOMId = ActualResultUOM.Id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UnitOfMeasures AchievementUOM ON dbo.Achievements.ObjectiveAchievementUOMId = AchievementUOM.Id
GROUP BY dbo.Objectives.Id,
    dbo.Achievements.ActualResult, 
    dbo.Objectives.Clause, 
    dbo.Objectives.FrequencyId, 
    ObjectiveFrequency.Title,               
    dbo.Objectives.ObjectiveCategoryId, 
    dbo.ObjectiveCategories.Category, 
    dbo.Objectives.Target, 
    dbo.Objectives.TargetUnitId, 
    TargetUOM.Unit, 
    TargetUOM.Symbole, 
    TargetUOM.Position,                 
    dbo.Achievements.ActualResultUOMId, 
    ActualResultUOM.Unit, 
    ActualResultUOM.Symbole, 
    ActualResultUOM.Position
```

OUTPUT
[image]

I want to get average of actual result according to objectId. Please help.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the `OVER` clause? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are averaging the `Achievements.ActualResult` but added it in the `GROUP BY` clause. Please remove it from the `GROUP BY` as below:

```
GROUP BY dbo.Objectives.Id,
    dbo.Objectives.Clause, 
    dbo.Objectives.FrequencyId, 
    ObjectiveFrequency.Title,               
    dbo.Objectives.ObjectiveCategoryId, 
    dbo.ObjectiveCategories.Category, 
    dbo.Objectives.Target, 
    dbo.Objectives.TargetUnitId, 
    TargetUOM.Unit, 
    TargetUOM.Symbole, 
    TargetUOM.Position,                 
    dbo.Achievements.ActualResultUOMId, 
    ActualResultUOM.Unit, 
    ActualResultUOM.Symbole, 
    ActualResultUOM.Position
```

Comment: thanks satishcse. it worked